# Apache Camel + ActiveMQ. Too slow message transporting between 2 brokers

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm trying to transfer messages between 2 ActiveMQ brokers through Apache Camel and the trouble is that I can achive rate of transportation only about 135 messages per second. I want to increase that number.
The situation is I have 2 ActiveMQ brokers on remote server. I want to take messages from queue on first broker and transfer these messages to several queues on second broker via Camel route.

```
this is how I establish connections:
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin", "admin", "tcp://10.1**.6.195:62222");
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory2 = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin", "admin", "tcp://10.1**.6.195:
            PooledConnectionFactory pf1 = new PooledConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            pf1.setMaximumActiveSessionPerConnection(45);
            pf1.setMaxConnections(40);
            PooledConnectionFactory pf2 = new PooledConnectionFactory(connectionFactory2);
            pf2.setMaximumActiveSessionPerConnection(45);
            pf2.setMaxConnections(40);
            context.addComponent("broker1", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(pf1));
            context.addComponent("broker2", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(pf2));
```

my route:

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() {
                onException(SetParamsException.class)
                    .filter()
                    .method(new IsDisableFlowLoggingFilter(), "filter")
                    .process(new CreateErrorHandlerLogMessageProcessor())
                    .to("broker2:queue:ESB.EVENT.LOGGING");

                from(fromBroker+":queue:"+sourceQueue+"?maxConcurrentConsumers=500&concurrentConsumers=40&asyncConsumer=true")
                    .process(new SetParamsProcessor())
                        .to("seda:EVENT.LOGGING")
                        .to("seda:EVENT.TRANSACTION.LOGGING")
                        .to("seda:EVENT.MONITOR.LOG")
                        .to("xslt:file://transform.xsl")
                            .to("broker2:queue:testMQDestinationOLOLO?maxConcurrentConsumers=500&concurrentConsumers=20&asyncConsumer=true")
                from("seda:EVENT.LOGGING")
                    .filter()
                    .method(new IsDisableFlowLoggingFilter(), "filter")
                    .process(new CreateEventMessageProcessor())
                    .to("broker2:queue:EVENT.LOGGING");

                from("seda:EVENT.TRANSACTION.LOGGING")
                    .process(new CreateTransactionDetailsMessageProcessor())
                    .to("broker2:queue:EVENT.TRANSACTION.LOGGING");

                from("seda:EVENT.MONITOR.LOG")
                    .process(new CreateMonitoringMessageProcessor())
                    .to("broker2:queue:EVENT.MONITOR.LOG");
            }
        });
        context.start();
```

This configuration gives me ~135 messages per second. I think that because my consumers work successively instead of parallel. Can anyone around help me with rate increasing?

PS: btw, ping to remote server ~2ms

Answer (score 0):

That is quite a bit of logging going on, I would recommend cutting down on that.  Otherwise, it looks like you are using xslt on the message which might be quite slow considering usual xslt speeds.  I would also recommend posting your ActiveMQConnectionFactory configurations.  I would strongly recommend running these on pools with larger numbers of sessions.  I currently use both camel and activemq in production with very fast rates.  Here is a sample factory you could model off of:

```
<bean id="myAmqBean" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" destroy-method="doStop">
    <property name="configuration">
        <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
            <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="20" />
            <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="20" />
            <property name="acceptMessagesWhileStopping" value="true" />
            <property name="connectionFactory">
                <bean class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
                    <property name="maxConnections" value="10" />
                    <property name="MaximumActiveSessionPerConnection" value="500" />
                    <property name="connectionFactory">
                        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
                            <property name="brokerURL" value="${activemq1.brokerUrl}" />
                            <property name="userName" value="${activemq1.username}" />
                            <property name="password" value="${activemq1.password}" />
                            <property name="dispatchAsync" value="true" />
                            <property name="alwaysSessionAsync" value="true" />
                            <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true" />
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Comment: I cut off everything but last 'to' endpoint. So my route now is `from(fromBroker+":queue:"+sourceQueue+"?maxConcurrentConsumers=500&concurrentCo‌​nsumers=40&asyncConsumer=true").to("broker2:queue:testMQDestinationOLOLO?maxConcu‌​rrentConsumers=500&concurrentConsumers=20&asyncConsumer=true")` but it hardly increased transporting speed (about 145 message per second). I'd like to post ActiveMQConnectionFactory configurations, but I already posted everything I have

Comment: Sorry missed your activeMQ connection factories earlier.  I would definitely  recommend having more default connections and setting your factory up similar to mine.  (I set it up using spring, but you can do it in java as well).  You can also modify the ActiveMQ to keep your messages in memory instead of on disk as well via the ActiveMQ.xml file.